# How to set no proxy for InternetExplorerDriver

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

My IE Browser was set proxy before. I want to set direct connection (no proxy) when initializing a new InternetExplorerDriver instance in run time. I can do it with FirefoxProfile but not with DesiredCapabilities. The code below just set specified proxy but not set no proxy. 
Could you please help me to set no proxy for InternetExplorerDriver?

```
String PROXY = "localhost:8080";

org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy(PROXY)
     .setFtpProxy(PROXY)
     .setSslProxy(PROXY);
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(cap);
```

I would have something like that:

```
Proxy proxy = Proxy.NO_Proxy;
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(cap);
```

## ***[EDIT]***

```
String ieDriverPath = Constants.PROJECT_PATH + "\\src\\lib\\handler\\IEDriverServer.exe";
        DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
        proxy.setProxyType(org.openqa.selenium.Proxy.ProxyType.DIRECT);
        ieCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);

        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", ieDriverPath);
        WebDriver webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);
        webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Constants.SE_WAIT_IN_SECOND, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The code above didn't work. The failure as below:

```
Aug 14, 2013 9:09:57 AM org.openqa.selenium.browserlaunchers.WindowsProxyManager backupRegistrySettings
INFO: Backing up registry settings...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Bug extracting hudsuckr
    at org.openqa.selenium.browserlaunchers.WindowsProxyManager.extractHudsuckr(WindowsProxyManager.java:575)
    at org.openqa.selenium.browserlaunchers.WindowsProxyManager.runHudsuckr(WindowsProxyManager.java:585)
    at org.openqa.selenium.browserlaunchers.WindowsProxyManager.backupHudsuckrSettings(WindowsProxyManager.java:624)
    at org.openqa.selenium.browserlaunchers.WindowsProxyManager.backupRegistrySettings(WindowsProxyManager.java:286)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.prepareProxy(InternetExplorerDriver.java:296)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.run(InternetExplorerDriver.java:180)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:174)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:147)
    at acccm.Testing.TID02.main(TID02.java:52)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to locate: hudsuckr/hudsuckr.exe
    at org.openqa.selenium.io.FileHandler.locateResource(FileHandler.java:86)
    at org.openqa.selenium.io.FileHandler.copyResource(FileHandler.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.browserlaunchers.WindowsProxyManager.extractHudsuckr(WindowsProxyManager.java:572)
    ... 8 more

Selenium version: 2.33
OS: Win 7 64 bit
Browser: IE
Browser version: 8,9
```

I would appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work for you:

```
// WARNING! Untested code written from memory without the
// aid of an IDE. May not run or even compile as written
// here. Modify as necessary.
org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
proxy.setProxyType(org.openqa.selenium.Proxy.ProxyType.DIRECT);

DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);

// Only needed for Java (not for other languages), and requires
// version 2.35 or higher of WebDriver. Should bypass the Java
// server proxy setting routines and use the native IEDriverServer.exe
// ones.
cap.setCapability("ie.setProxyByServer", true);

WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(cap);
```

Comment: Thanks JimEvans. But your code didn't work. It was failed. Please see my EDIT section above for more details. BTW, Could you please help me to fix that problem? I appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an additional capability. If you're using 2.35 of Selenium, that should get you where you need to go.

Answer (score 0):

Setting proxy for IE driver requires hudsuckr.exe which is shipped in selenium-server-standalone jars.

Adding this to the classpath should solve your problem.